# Output matrix for system with accelerometer

Tags: control-engineering, instrumentation

Consider a generic second order state space SISO system

\begin{equation}
\left[ \begin{array}{c}{\dot{\tilde{x}}_{1}} \\ {\dot{x}_{2}}\end{array}\right]=A \left[ \begin{array}{c}{\tilde{x}_{1}} \\ {\tilde{x}_{2}}\end{array}\right]+B \tilde{u}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\mathbf{\tilde{y}}=C \left[ \begin{array}{c}{\tilde{x}_{1}} \\ {\tilde{x}_{2}}\end{array}\right]
\end{equation}

We can interpret $\tilde{x}_1$ as the position, $\tilde{x}_2$ as the velocity, and $\dot{\tilde{x}}_2$ as the acceleration. If I were to measure the state of my system using an accelerometer, how would I include it in this model? Is there a way of choosing matrix $C$ such that $\tilde{y}=\dot{\tilde{x}}_2$?

My first intuition would be to copy the equation for $\dot{\tilde{x}}_2$

\begin{equation}
\mathbf{\tilde{y}}=a_{21}\tilde{x}_{1} + a_{22}\tilde{x}_{2} + b_{2}\tilde{u}
\end{equation}

though I am not sure about that. Having a direct input-to-output term would mean that the system had infinite bandwidth (and therefore an instantaneous response).

Comment: What are you trying to do with this system model?  If you're doing sensor fusion, then you use the accelerometer output as an input to the system's modeled dynamics, i.e. (simplified version) $ \ddot x = a$

Comment: If you think an instantaneous measurement is not realistic you could add a delay.